# Search <Li> List via children text

Tags: python, html

so I'm currently using python to import data from an excel sheet and then take that information and use it to fill out a form on a webpage.

The problem I'm having is selecting a profile of the drop-down menu.

I've been using the Selenium library and I can actually select the element using find_element_by_xpath assuming, but that's assuming I know the data value, the data value is auto-generated for each new profile that's added so I can't use that as a reliable means.

```
Profile = Browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/something/something/.....")
Profile.click()
time.sleep(0.75)  #allowing time for link to be clickable
The_Guy = Browser.find_element_by-xpath("/html/something/something/...")
The_Guy.click()
```

This works only on known paths I would like to do something like this

```
Profile = Browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/something/something/.....")
Profile.click()
time.sleep(0.75)  #allowing time for link to be clickable
The_Guy = Browser.find_element_by_id("Caption.A")
The_Guy.click()
```

EXAMPLE OF HTML

```
    <ul class ="list">
    <li class = "option" data-value= XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XX-XXX>
       ::marker
        Thor
    </li>
    <li class = "option" data-value= XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XX-XXX>
       ::marker
        IronMan
    </li>
    <li class = "option" data-value= XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XX-XXX>
       ::marker
        Caption.A
    </li>
    ....
    </ul>
```

What I'll like to be able to do is search via name (like Caption.A) and then step back to select the parent Li. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following xpath to find the li containing desired text and then click on it. Sample code:

```
driver.find_element(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'Caption.A')]")).click()
```

Hope it helps :)